# Protecting my MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, protection, circuit-protection, powermosfet

I'm working on a circuit to turn on and off a set of lights on a vehicle.

I have to do the switching on the high side of the lights and need to use a positive voltage to trigger them on. So, I've got a little NPN transistor that grounds the gate of my P-Channel FET when it gets voltage and sends current from the battery to the light.

[image]

It works great breadboarded out but I am concerned about protecting the MOSFET and (maybe the BJT) when it's on a vehicle. Do I need a Zener or TVS diode somewhere? Where should it go? What does it need to do? What values do I need to look for when sourcing it? I am more than happy with overkill.

This is the FET I was planning on using: [SQJ459EP](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Siliconix/SQJ459EP-T1_GE3/?qs=Vcr9%2FL0R50hdpSKYYGJv%252bQ%3D%3D). It has a diode built in between the drain and the source but it might need something to protect the gate?

Thank you guys for any help you can give me!

Edit: Fixed Schematic

Comment: That circuit won't turn off a load because of the MOSFETs body diode conducting.

Comment: WOW my brain is having a seizure trying to understand if that works drawn that way up...

Comment: Where does INPUT come from?

Comment: I drew it up a little quick and I guess I flipped the Source and the Drain. 

For the input, it will probably be tapped into the low beam or an aux circuit that comes on with the key.

Comment: I would use something in a DPAK or D2PAK. I don't like those fet's due to the small clearance between drain and source, hidden under the package.

Answer (score 1):

For auto stuff you need TVS diodes pretty much on every input and output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD3chY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'd also add D1 to protect you from kickback in the lines to the lamps.

Comment: Might as well put a Zener across Vgs of M1 as well, no? Unless the part has protection built in.

Comment: @mkeith yes why not...

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the precautions and tests required by Automotive designers, there are many smart switches to choose from.

**[e.g.Infineon BTS50060](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies/BTS500601TEAAUMA2/BTS500601TEAAUMA2TR-ND/4842139)** $2.50 (1pc)
- 6mΩ with 60A (min.) inrush current
- optimized edge shaping during switching
- 3.3V and 5V compatible logic inputs
- Advanced analog load current sense signal
- intelligent Latch
- overload and over temperature protection with defined diagnostic signal

**Key Benefits**
- Low switching losses
- EMC optimized performance
- direct connection to the uC
- Easy current sense calibration
- Latched switch-off and reporting in case of fault condition
- protection from ESD, loss of ground, loss of V+, overvoltage